# Variadic macro that takes 0 or 1 arguments?

Tags: objective-c, c, c-preprocessor

How would you write a variadic macro that can take either 1 or 0 arguments. I.e. something like this:

```
GREET()         // returns @"Hello World"
GREET(@"John")  // returns @"Hello John"
```

Comment: This is objective-c, then, due to your use of the `@"string"` idiom, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite simple, you have something like this:

```
#define __NARGS(unused, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, VAL, ...) VAL
#define NARGS(...) __NARGS(unused, ## __VA_ARGS__, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)

#define __GREET(ARGC, ARGS...) GREET_ ## ARGC (ARGS)
#define _GREET(ARGC, ARGS...) __GREET(ARGC, ARGS)
#define GREET(...) _GREET(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

#define GREET_0(...) @"Hello World!"
#define GREET_1(ARG, ...) @"Hello, " ARG // strings are auto-concatenated in objc

int main()
{
    NSLog(@"%@", GREET());
    NSLog(@"%@", GREET(@"John"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
2012-09-30 11:56:48.478 TestProj[51823:303] Hello World!
2012-09-30 11:56:48.480 TestProj[51823:303] Hello, John
```

Now, this is quite complex, but assuming you understand at a basic level how the preprocessor works, you should be in a good position to understand what is happening.

Comment: Awesome. "quite simple", though? ;)

Comment: @JimBuck when you compare it to some other stuff I've done (a `switch` statement that supports objc objects, object-scoped local variables, writing       an entire app in C for God's sake) this is actually very simple.

Comment: I am not too familiar with objective C, but in C your macro would use a gcc extension "eat-the-comma". This would not be portable to standard C. (There is another standard-conforming way to check for empty macro arguments, it is a little bit more involved.)

Comment: @JensGustedt I'm well aware of that. But considering that GCC (and clang, which supports this extension too) is the main compiler of ObjcC (I don't know of many others), this should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this would work for objective C, but for C99 and C11 you can use [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) that has a meta macro `P99_IF_EMPTY`

```
#define GREET(...) P99_IF_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__)("Hello World")("Hello " __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Considering the fact that objc uses exactly the same pre-proccesor as C, I don't see why this wouldn't work. +1.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is to build a data structure with a repeating element, such as:

```
union greet_arg {
  char *string;
};
struct greet_args {
  union greet_arg *arg[2];
};
void greet_function(struct greet_args *x);
```

Your macro can then be implemented like this:

```
#define GREET(x...)  greet_function(&(struct greet_args){0, x})
```

Now the reason this works is that if you call `GREET("foo")` then you get:

```
greet_function(&(struct greet_args){0, "foo"});
```

whereas if you call `GREET()` you get:

```
greet_function(&(struct greet_args){0, });
```

which is *still* valid; the "0" simply null-fills the rest of the array.

Your `greet_function()` then simply check `x->arg[1]`.

Comment: Interesting, but do note that this does cause the (minimal) overhead of creating a local-scoped iVar, due to the C99 compound literal you made.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - Under `gcc -O2`, it actually produces the exact same assembly as your example, and has the benefit of actually working with non-literal arguments.

Comment: you have to remember that most objc users won't be using GCC, instead using clang. I'd strongly urge you to re-test there.

Comment: Just did `clang -Os`: gcc produces better code than clang. Nevertheless, between your example and mine the assembly output is the same. This is such a trivial optimisation, I can't imagine why anyone would expect the compiler to handle this trivial unboxing poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Either a macro has variadic arguments, or it has a fixed number of arguments. To get the desired result, declare 2 macros, one with 0 parameters and one with 1 parameter.